# ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Undefined index: name laravel 7

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have clone my project from heroku and am using wampserver and composer version 2. Can someone help me to understand why am I get this error.

In PackageManifest.php line 131:

Undefined index: name

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Comment: What do you mean by "get this error"? What kind of action do you perform that provokes this error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ErrorException (E\_NOTICE) Undefined index: name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64626462/errorexception-e-notice-undefined-index-name)

Answer (score 3):

```
 composer update laravel/framework
```

The above step solves the issue.
I had same issue with my composer installer, after updating composer it works
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I had the exact same error the other day, and for me, the solution was to downgrade the composer with:

```
composer self-update --1
```

Don't know if you will accept this as an answer, but that's what worked for me.

Comment: $ignoreAll = in_array('*', $ignore = $this->packagesToIgnore());

        $this->write(collect($packages)->mapWithKeys(function ($package) {
            return [$this->format($package['name']) => $package['extra']['laravel'] ?? []];
        })->each(function ($configuration) use (&$ignore) {
            $ignore = array_merge($ignore, $configuration['dont-discover'] ?? []);
        })->reject(function ($configuration, $package) use ($ignore, $ignoreAll) {
            return $ignoreAll || in_array($package, $ignore);
        })->filter()->all());

Comment: Hi thanks. Error still persist and I have downgraded.